# Is this a good computer chair for everyday computer use?

Tags: ergonomics

This is the computer chair I use:
[image]

I'm a web developer who sits in this chair from morning until I sleep. Recently, I started to get back pains. I know I'm too young to have them. Can it be due to this chair? It's a small chair which doesn't extend up to my shoulders. Is it a good choice or do I need to change to a larger chair (which extends up to my shoulders) soon?

Comment: While a computer chair could be considered "hardware" it is not computer hardware. If you want to know if a chair is bad for your back then see a doctor or physiotherapist who will know about that sort of thing.

Comment: You guys could [really](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics) [be](http://superuser.com/questions/135183/how-far-from-the-computer-screen-is-it-recommended-to-sit?rq=1) [more](http://superuser.com/questions/52722/my-fingers-are-cold-when-using-my-computer-solutions?rq=1) [consistent](http://superuser.com/questions/2047/what-health-and-ergonomic-factors-should-an-all-day-computer-user-take-into-acco?rq=1) at moderation.

Comment: @peelman remember that all users above 3000 rep (such as your good self) can vote to close a question. Since there are quite a few of us, we will not always be consistent. That said, this question is clearly off topic, whether other, similar questions have been left open or not is irrelevant. In any case, you link to mostly very old questions (all of which are more general than this one) and a tag half of whose questions (51% at time of writing) have been closed. I think we're pretty consistent with this one :).

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to get up every hour and stretch, regardless of whatever chair you happen to be sporting. Humans are not designed to sit in a chair 14+ hours a day, period.

Comment: Very true. We should all remember this!

Answer (score 2):

It certainly wouldn't be helping any pain you're feeling.  Having been through a dozen or so office chairs, the nicest one I've ever had has been a Herman Miller Aeron.  Unfortunately it stayed with the office when I left the position.  You need to look at the chair as an investment.  even an expensive chair is cheaper than the medical bills you could incur from serious back problems later.

Look around at what's available; Herman Miller makes several different models at different price points, and they are well regarded as some of the most ergonomic chairs currently made.

Comment: Do whatever you must to get an Aeron or equivalent. It will be the best $850 you ever spent.  Sit4Less.com is the recommended vendor.  Everyone sells them for the same price, but twice a year they have a 15% off sale.